# Truffle ganache error

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, testing, ganache

I have this error~!

Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Can you help me thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no information about your deployment/testing methodology in the OP.

Here's a likely cause. Ganache blockchains are transient. Each time you restart ganache it's a new network with a new network id. Any previous deployments/migrations will not be present.

Make it your habit to `$ truffle migrate --reset` when you restart ganache. You'll see evidence of how many unique ganache networks your contracts have been deployed to with `$ truffle networks`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have done it and i can see my network as i have named it in the truffle-config.js